# HH100 : Network rinkebey doesnt exists

Tags: solidity, hardhat, rinkeby, hardhat-deploy

[image]

I am writing a hardhat program and here's my hardhat.config.js

```js
require("dotenv").config()
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
const RINKBEY_RPC_URL = process.env.RINKBEY_RPC_URL
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
    // defaultNetwork : 'hardhat' default with built in RPC URL.
    solidity: "0.8.9",
    networks: {
        rinkbey: {
            url: RINKBEY_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 4,
        },
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },
}
```

when I run `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby` 
I get Network rinkeby doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

rinkeby is spelled wrong in your config file

Comment: happens to the best of us